# select-from-where-and-case How can I make these work together?

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

```
with rows as 

(select 
candidate,
decision,
comments,

candidate
scores, 
rankings

from 
candidate_decision_file,
candidate_info_file 

where candidate_decision_file.candidate = candidate_info_file.candidate

and condition
and condition
and condition
and condition
and condition
and condition


group by candidate,
decision,
comments,

candidate
scores, 
rankings


order by candidate_decision_file.candidate
)


select * from rows
```

Decision has 3 options: good, bad or fair. what I want to do is select whatever each candidate has but add a case/when/then statement such that if the decision is fair, I check comments. If comments contain 'maybe' or 'probably', then select fair. If comments don't contain 'maybe' or 'probably' then don't select fair i.e. don't select that whole data point.

I would appreciate assistance.

Comment: Please give table definition and sample data, as text or a DBfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
WHERE decision <> 'Fair'
OR (decision = 'Fair' AND 
        (comments LIKE '%maybe%' OR comments LIKE '%probably%')
   )
```